# How to pull an entire project from TFS

Tags: command-line-interface, tf-cli

While sifting through [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) I figured I'd ask if anyone knows how to download an entire project using the tfs command line utility.  It doesn't look like I need the get command... but I can't find anything that looks like what I want.  If I have an empty folder I'd like to map a project to some subfolder tfs will make when downloading the project.  Like 'git clone project-url',  any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little verbose from the command line.  You need to create a workspace, map a working folder and then do a get.

Something like this:

```
tf workspace /new TempWorkspace /collection:http://tfsServer:8080/tfs/defaultcollection /noprompt
tf workfold /unmap $/ /workspace:TempWorkspace
tf workfold /map "$/Project/Path/SomeFolder" localFolderName /workspace:TempWorkspace
tf get
```

Note that the unmap is there because the workspace creation generally creates a default mapping for you.

As a further note if you like git you can always use git-tfs as a front end for TFS source control.